# Joining Tables based on Date Ranges

Tags: ms-access, join

I have an MS Access question

I have been struggling with a query containing a join with date ranges.
Found a couple off posts but don't get it to work

I have two tables.
One containing some data and a Due Date.

```
Table A 
Field 1, Field 2, Field 3, Due Date
```

The other table contains information about a period.

```
Table B
Periodname, Field X/Y/Z, StartDate, EndDate
```

I try to make a query with this output

```
Field 1, Field 2, Due Date, Periodname
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

In MsAccess you can actually write a join statement using `<` and `>`, although you cannot show it in the query editor.

```
SELECT [Field 1], [Field 2], [Field 3], [Due Date], PeriodName
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.[Due Date] >= B.StartDate AND A.DueDate <= B.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "join" by a *where* clause:

```
Select
    Field1, 
    Field2, 
    DueDate, 
    Periodname
From
    TableA,
    TableB
Where
    DueDate Between StartDate And EndDate
```

Comment: I managed to get it working with the Where, Obviously Issue there is that I only get records from Table A where there is a match with Table B.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I created so far
But I get a error on the "Between" command.
"You used the operator 'Between' without 'And'

SELECT Left([Q_Epics].[Component/s],3) AS Proj_Nr, Mid([Q_Epics].[Component/s],6,35) AS Project, Q_Epics.[Epic Key], Q_Epics.Summary, Q_Epics.Labels, Q_Epics.[Due Date], Sprints.Sprint AS Sprint

FROM Q_Epics

LEFT JOIN Sprints ON Q_Epics.[Due Date] BETWEEN [Sprints].[StartSprint] AND [Sprints].[EindeSprint]

GROUP BY Left([Q_Epics].[Component/s],3), Mid([Q_Epics].[Component/s],6,35), Q_Epics.[Epic Key], Q_Epics.Summary, Q_Epics.Labels, Q_Epics.[Due Date], Q_Epics.EpicStatus

HAVING (((Q_Epics.EpicStatus)<>"Closed"))

ORDER BY Q_Epics.[Due Date];

Answer (score 0):

In this version the error is: 
You try tu run a query where the expressin 'Sprints.Sprint' is not part of the static function

SELECT Left([Q_Epics].[Component/s],3) AS Proj_Nr, Mid([Q_Epics].[Component/s],6,35) AS Project, Q_Epics.[Epic Key], Q_Epics.Summary, Q_Epics.Labels, Q_Epics.[Due Date], Sprints.Sprint

FROM Q_Epics

Inner JOIN Sprints ON Q_Epics.[Due Date] >= [Sprints].[StartSprint] AND Q_Epics.[Due Date] <= [Sprints].[EindeSprint]

GROUP BY Left([Q_Epics].[Component/s],3), Mid([Q_Epics].[Component/s],6,35), Q_Epics.[Epic Key], Q_Epics.Summary, Q_Epics.Labels, Q_Epics.[Due Date], Q_Epics.EpicStatus

HAVING (((Q_Epics.EpicStatus)<>"Closed"))

ORDER BY Q_Epics.[Due Date];

Comment: Please use `Add comment` button instead of posting your comments as answers

Comment: Actually please use "Edit" on your question to add new code there.

Answer (score 0):

Done.
Combining your answers!! Thanks

SELECT Left([Q_Epics].[Component/s],3) AS Proj_Nr, Mid([Q_Epics].[Component/s],6,35) AS Project, Q_Epics.[Epic Key] AS [Epic Key], Q_Epics.Summary AS Summary, Q_Epics.Labels AS Labels, Q_Epics.[Due Date] AS [Due Date], [Sprints].[Sprint] AS Sprint

FROM Q_Epics

LEFT JOIN Sprints ON (Q_Epics.[Due Date] >= [Sprints].[StartSprint]) AND (Q_Epics.[Due Date] <= [Sprints].[EindeSprint])

WHERE (((Q_Epics.EpicStatus)<>"Closed"))

ORDER BY Q_Epics.[Due Date];